# Query AWS API Gateway Requests left from Quota and Usage plans management

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, api-gateway, quota

I need to control the access to a public API so the user can only make X request each month. I saw that the AWS has a built-in service to create and manage usage plans (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) associated to an API key. That looks great because has a throttle mechanism built-in and that can be hard to custom build and implement.

My question is:

**How can I query (from the lambda function) the "credits" left for a particular user (identified by the unique API key)?**
I only saw that AWS sends a 40x error when the quota limit is reached.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.